# Konva Draggable Rect with Children

Tags: react-konva

I want to add a draggable Rect (red in the screenshot below) with children (the icon and text in the screenshot below). Whenever I try this, I get this error:

```
TypeError: parentInstance.add is not a function
```

Here is the code of just trying to add the text:

```
<Rect x={0} y={0} width={200} height={100} draggable fill="red">              
    <Text text="Pencil" />                                                      
</Rect>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rect` or another other Konva shape can't have children elements. You can't nest on shape into another shape. For that case, you need to use [Groups](https://konvajs.org/docs/groups_and_layers/Groups.html)

```html
<Group x={0} y={0} draggable>
  <Rect width={200} height={100} fill="red" />
  <Text text="Pencil" />                                                      
</Group>
```

Comment: Oh AWESOME! Btw, I've memorized your name from the amount of answers you've provided about konva :). This is also a dumb question, but is there a way to put normal React components in a group?

Comment: If you mean DOM components, like `div` then no.